# Sum of all amount if charge dates are the same in Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I'm iterating over a [stripe charge object](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#charges) and I want to sum up the `amount` total for each day.

```
# Returns an array object of charges for a customer
@customer_charges = Stripe::Charge.all(:customer => current_user.stripeid)
```

Views:

```
<% @customer_charges.map do |c| %>
  On Monday, you were charged a total of <%= c.amount %>
<% end %>
```

Surely the above does nothing more than output lines of each charges but not the sum for the day. The difficulty I face is to sum up all charges for each day. Could someone point me in the right direction?

**The output would be like:**

```
"On Monday, you were charged a total of 200000"
"On Tueesday, you were charged a total of 500000"
etc...
```

**Instead of:**

```
On Monday, you were charged a total of 100000"
On Monday, you were charged a total of 100000"
etc...
```

My `view` looks messy with lines of `if statements` to compare dates and that does not look right.

Comment: You should probably be using `each` here instead of `map`. What is `created`? Is that a column or a method

Comment: Ok.  `created` is stripe's json unix timestamp: `"created": 1462001409,`

Comment: Why are you totalling timestamps? That makes no sense to me. If you need them as dates, `Time.at(timestamp)` will convert.

Comment: Made a typo. I have corrected it. The amount I needed

Comment: That's better. I still think `map` is a mistake here. Have you tried it with `each`? You probably want to use `Time.at(c.created).strftime('%A')` to get the day of week, not just have "Monday" in there for each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to iterate through each charge object in Stripe, storing the amount and the parsed date for each charge:

```
# Fetch charges in batches of 100 records from Stripe API, yield each individual charge to a block.
def each_stripe_charge_for_customer(customer_id)
  starting_after = nil
  loop do
    customer_charges = Stripe::Charge.all(customer: customer_id, limit: 100, starting_after: starting_after)
    break if customer_charges.none?
    charges.each do |charge|
      yield charge
    end
    starting_after = charges.data.last.id
  end
end

charges_by_date = Hash.new(0)

# For each Stripe charge, store the date and amount into a hash.
each_stripe_charge_for_customer(current_user.stripeid) do |stripe_charge|
  # Parses Stripe's timestamp to a Ruby date object. `to_date` converts a DateTime object to a date (daily resolution).
  charge_date = Time.at(stripe_charge.created).to_date
  charge_amount = stripe_charge.amount

  charges_by_date[charge_date] += charge_amount
end
```

Comment: This is all pretty decent, but a few things: `charges_by_date` could be `Hash.new(0)` if you want a default value of 0, that avoids the `||=` test later. `Date.strptime` is way clunkier than `Time.at` which does the job succinctly.

Comment: I'll have a go at this later. Thanks

Comment: @AnthonyE I'm just wondering, how you get to know this sort of code? Bruh.... this code is beautiful! Thanks!!!! But I need for the `current_user`: `charges = Stripe::Charge.all(:customer => current_user.stripeid, limit: 100, starting_after: starting_after)`

Comment: @Sylar Been coding a long time. :) If you need it for a specific user then just pass a `customer_id` to the `each_stripe_charge_for_customer` (See updated), which in turn, gets passed to the `customer` param of `Stripe::Charge.all`.