# Represent Stripe Charge Amount and Date with Chart.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

My code comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36951841/sum-of-all-amount-if-charge-dates-are-the-same-in-stripe/36952152#36952152) and Im displaying the data with [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) inside of a React component. Im using Rails 4. In the controller, the `charge props` comes out as: `@charges = charges_by_date = {}.as_json`

**jsx:**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("moneyHistory");
  var hash = this.props.charges;
  var amount = [];
  var d = [];
  var chargeDate = Object.keys(hash).forEach(function(k) {
    var cost = hash[k];
    var date = moment(k).format("Do MMM");
    amount.push(cost);
    d.push(date);
  });
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: d.sort(),
          datasets: [{
              label: 'Amount',
              data: amount.sort(),
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 126, 255, 0.72)',
              borderColor: '#1b6ac9',
              width: 100
          }]
      },
      options: {
          scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                  ticks: {
                      beginAtZero:true
                  }
              }]
          }
      }
  });
},

render: function() {
  return(
    <div>
      <canvas id="moneyHistory" width="400" height="150"></canvas>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Chart displays great but I want to have 7 days on the graph (today + 6 days ago). I want to replace the `hash` dates with:

```
var staticDates = [
      moment().subtract(6, 'days').format("Do MMM"),
      moment().subtract(5, 'days').format("Do MMM"),
      moment().subtract(4, 'days').format("Do MMM"),
      moment().subtract(3, 'days').format("Do MMM"),
      moment().subtract(2, 'days').format("Do MMM"),
      moment().subtract(1, 'days').format("Do MMM"),
      moment().subtract(0, 'days').format("Do MMM")
    ];

...
 data: {
   labels: staticDates,
...
```

Now, I need to associate those charge with those date. How to achieve this?

Edit:

I'd like this dates on the graph to be like this where today's date (30th Apr) always be on the right:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to do all this date processing in Javascript. Let Ruby/Rails do the heavy lifting for you.

Suppose you have a method that maps charges to a date, where each key in the hash is a day and the value is a count:

```
def each_stripe_charge_for_customer(customer_id, created)
  starting_after = nil
  loop do
    customer_charges = Stripe::Charge.all customer: customer_id, 
                                          created: created, 
                                          limit: 100, 
                                          starting_after: starting_after
    break if customer_charges.none?
    customer_charges.each do |charge|
      yield charge
    end
    starting_after = customer_charges.data.last.id
  end
end

def daily_charges_for_customer(customer_id, created=nil)
  charges_by_date = Hash.new(0)

  # For each Stripe charge, store the date and amount into a hash.
  each_stripe_charge_for_customer(customer_id, created) do |stripe_charge|
    # Parses Stripe's timestamp to a Ruby date object. `to_date` converts a DateTime object to a date (daily resolution).
    charge_date = Time.at(stripe_charge.created).to_date
    charge_amount = stripe_charge.amount

    charges_by_date[charge_date] += charge_amount
  end

  charges_by_date
end
```

So now, `daily_charges_for_customer(customer_id, 1.week.ago.to_i)` returns something like:

```
{
  '19 Jan' => 10,
  '20 Jan' => 20
}
```

*You should cache this result whenever possible so you're not constantly hitting the Stripe API*

Now, you can pass this as a `data-attribute` within the DOM:

**In your view:**

```
<%= content_tag :canvas, "", id: "myChart", width: "400", height: "200", data: { charges: daily_charges_for_customer(customer_id, 1.week.ago.to_i) } %>
```

This will simplify your javascript considerably:

**In your JS code:**

```
var ctx = $("#moneyHistory");

var cumulative_daily_charges = ctx.data("charges");
var date_labels = Object.keys(cumulative_daily_charges);
var daily_charges = date_labels.map(function(v) { return cumulative_daily_charges[v]; });

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: date_labels,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Date',
        data: daily_charges
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
});
```

I'm writing this sort of "off the cuff" so you may need to fix some typos/syntax errors, but the logic and major nuts-and-bolts should work. Let me know if you run into any issues.

**EDIT**

Also, I don't think `amount.sort()` and `d.sort()` will act as you expect them to. If they're separate arrays, they'll be sorted independently.

Comment: I'm almost there with your answer but Im not getting the list of 7 days (1 week ago). I'm using `react-rails` so my view is: `<%= react_component "MyComponent", {charges: @charges} )` where `@charges` is `charges_by_date = Hash.new(0)`

Comment: What are you getting instead?

Comment: I only see the dates where a charge was made. What I want is, see edit of post.

Comment: If it's complicated, which I think it is, I may just leave it as your answer.

Comment: I think this is more of a deficiency with Chart.js. As far as I know, it doesn't have any interpolation ability, so will only show values for dates which are present. I could be wrong, however.

Comment: No worries. This is just a startup so this will do for now. But hey, it works. Thanks. BTW. the `sort()` makes the current date on the right ;)