# Sum of all amount if created_at dates are the same in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to [replicate this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36951841/sum-of-all-amount-if-charge-dates-are-the-same-in-stripe/36952152) with the Rails database (pg) query but not having much luck.

My `Foo` table has many columns but I'm interested in `created_at` and `amount`.

`Foo.all.where(client_id: 4)` looks like this:

```
[
  [0] {:created_at => <date>, :amount => 20},
  [1] {:created_at => <different date>, :amount => 5},
  ...
]
```

[Stripe Charge Object](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#retrieve_charge) is in json so I thought I could:

```
f = Foo.all.where(client_id: 4).as_json # could I?
```

**Anyhow, my controller:**

```
# As per first link above
def each_user_foo
  starting_after = nil
  loop do
    f = Foo.all.where(client_id: 4).as_json
    #f_hash = Hash[f.each_slice(2).to_a] # I was trying something here
    break if f.none?
    f.each do |bar|
      yield bar
    end
    starting_after = bar.last.id
  end
end

foo_by_date = Hash.new(0)

each_user_foo do |f|
  # Parses date object. `to_date` converts a DateTime object to a date (daily resolution).
  amount_date = DateTime.strptime(f.created_at.to_s, "%s").to_date # line 50
  amount = f.amount

  # Initialize the amount for this date to 0.
  foo_by_date[amount_date] ||= 0

  foo_by_date[amount_date] += amount
end
```

My error at line 50 is:

> undefined method `created_at' for Hash

I guess an object is still in an array somewhere. Also, is there an equivalent for the JS `console.log()` in Rails? Would be handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `f` is stored as a Hash object by calling `as_json`, yet you're treating it like a plain-old Ruby object in your `each_user_foo` block by using the `.` operator.

The solution is to use the hash accessor operator instead (eg `f[:created_at]`). You also don't need to stringify and parse the date because it's already a `DateTime` object:

```
amount_date = f[:created_at].to_date # line 50
amount = f[:amount]
```

Also, `Foo` is a model class right? If so, I'd recommend using `pluck` to get the attributes you need, which will be more efficient and cleaner than calling `as_json`:

```
# As per first link above
def each_user_foo
    f = Foo.where(client_id: 4).pluck(:created_at, :amount)
    f.each do |bar|
      yield(bar.first, bar.last)
    end
end

foo_by_date = Hash.new(0)

each_user_foo do |created_at, amount|
  # Parses date object. `to_date` converts a DateTime object to a date (daily resolution).
  amount_date = created_at.to_date # line 50
  foo_by_date[amount_date] += amount
end
```

You can remove this line as well:

```
foo_by_date[amount_date] ||= 0
```

Since you're using an initializer in your `foo_by_date = Hash.new(0)` variable assignment).

**EDIT**

If you're using Postgres, just do:

```
Foo.where(client_id: 4).group("date_trunc('day', created_at)").sum(:amount)
```

Or for MySQL:

```
Foo.where(client_id: 4).group("DAY(created_at)").sum(:amount)
```

Much, much simpler than your current approach.

The equivalent of `console.log()` in Rails is `Rails.logger.info()`, you can also use `Rails.logger.warn()` and `Rails.logger.error()`. Really, any function that outputs to `STDOUT`, such as `puts` and `print` will output to your console.

Comment: Ahh thanks. Im now getting `undefined method `[]' for Sun, 01 May 2016 07:07:35 UTC +00:00:Time` when I use `pluck`.

Comment: Let me double check everything.

Comment: `undefined method to_date for nil:NilClass` on same line. I am now using `f = Hash[Foo.where(client_id: 4).pluck(:created_at, :amount)]` instead of my first. Correct?

Comment: Close. `pluck()` returns an array. Use `f = Foo.all.where(client_id: 4).pluck(:created_at, :amount)` and yield each element of the array in your block with `yield Hash[bar]`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Forgot to delete, sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110751/discussion-between-anthony-e-and-sylar).